# CSS unequal div boxes

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I am trying to show a `div` `foreach` row in my database. Now here is the html code I have now:

```
<div class="column middle">
    <table>

    <?php

        $row_count = $result->num_rows;
        $i = 0;

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            if ($i == 0 or $i == 2)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<div class='list_column'>
                      <form method='post' action='producten.php'>
                      <input type='hidden' name='restaurant_id' value=".$row['id']." />
                      <div class='foto'><img src='".$row['picture']."' style='width: 100%; height: 25%;'/></div>
                      <div class='name'>".$row['name']."</div>
                      <button type='submit' class='order'>Bestellen</button>
                      </form>
                      </div>";
            echo "</td>";
            
            $i += 1;
            
            if ($i == 2)
            {
                $i = 0;
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>

    </table>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.column.middle {
  width: 60%;
}
.list_column {
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    width:50%;
}
.list_column:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #e5e5e5;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.list_column .name {
    font-weight:bold;
    }
.list_column .order {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #F68B1E;
    border: 1px solid #F68B1E;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.list_column .order:hover {
    background: #f17e0a;
    border-color: #f17e0a;
}
```

Now here is my current result:
[image]

As you can see the `divs` don't have equal sizes. What I want is that the images in the `divs` are squares and that the div size of `list_column` is equal to each other, even with images that are not squared and equal.

How can I do that?

Comment: Well.... If someone can give me a property or something I can work with it is enough, but now I have nothing and I struggled for a few time with this problem now. So if you have suggestions of what css properties I need to use, it would be very helpful!

Comment: Why you use a table for layout?

Comment: do not use tables for layout. You are not in the 90s anymore! Use divs to prepare the layout and assign them width in % for a quick fix. But do not nest a div inside a table cell. Afaik should not even be valid html at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fix size of the image (Ex: 250x250). With your code above, you style the image with `width:100%`. If the size of images are not the same, the column will like your result image.

Comment: Is there no way I can use with percentages?

Comment: it's hard to use percentages that because the size of images are different. But if you want to do this, i recommend you fix the width of the image to exact pixel. Ex: you have 4 image and the size of images (300, 200, 500, 200), you choose the minimum width and let the heigth auto. Another way, you can fix the box that bound the image like (400x400), the image will fix to the parent.